# How to create tile interface in wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

Can anyone tell me how do i achieve grid view interface in wpf project. I am trying to create a sqaure tile interface which i want to bind with a List data structure such that it will populate and create the same number of tiles as that of List's count. The image given below might help you in understanding the type of interface. I know this might be a silly question but i am stuck. Thanx for your help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As often in such situations, use the [`ItemsControl` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For the [`ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can use a [`WrapPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will create the effect of "filling up lines" and wrapping once the horizontal space is used up.

Then, in order to create a grid-like appearance (i.e. not only rows, but also visible columns), make sure that each item is displayed with the same size - that is something that you should be able to ensure in the [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your `ItemsControl`, for example by using one of the following to ways:

- You can manually assign fixed values to the `Width` and `Height` properties of your item views (that is, the root elements of your item templates).
- You can use a grid in the item templates and ensure the equal size by using shared size groups for the column and row definitions.

Comment: Can you guide me through a tutorial or something. Or you can may be provide some links to tutorial please.

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi: Tutorial for what aspect in particular? That said, I don't know any particular tutorials. Most of what I know about WPF, I learned directly from people with more experience in it.

Comment: Actually your hyperlinks in the above answer provided some great info to me. Just tell me one more thing, can i click those tiles to navigate to other forms or execute some code like that.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I never did like MSDN's examples for an `ItemsControl`, so wrote my own [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/). That should show you the XAML you need, and just add a click event to your `ItemTemplate` to handle clicking on items

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi: Sure, the key are the item templates you define - they can contain any UI elements you like, not only for displaying information, but also interactive elements such as buttons that can bring up other views. Have a look at the command pattern built around the [`ICommand` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is a clean way to provide some interaction logic for those buttons.

Comment: @Rachel: Skimming over your example, the `UniformGrid` seems to be another suitable items panel class for the OP.